# What does the forward slash operator do when applied to string types in C++?

Tags: c++, string, stl, operator-overloading, std

I found this C++ code:

`std::string   fruit = "" / "apple";`

When stepping with Visual Studio 12 over this line, the `fruit` variable ends up containing *apple*.
What does the forward slash operator do when applied to string types in C++?

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? https://wandbox.org/permlink/MnjmYdZGZ9vUKAXG

Comment: Your code doesn't compile on my VS2017, please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Just because it doesn't compile doesn't mean it's not a valid question.  The fact that standard C++ does not have a implantation for the forward slash operator doesn't mean this is a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The division operator is not defined by the C++ standard library for `string` nor for `const char[N]`. So this [code won't compile by itself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29e5353c5ac959c4)

You likely have somewhere else in the code an overload that takes two strings or two `const char[]` which actually does concatenate its two operands, i.e.

```
std::string operator/(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This question closed because of poor quality, could you please remove the answer, so I could delete this question?